# MySQL IN only deleting single row, should delete multiple from variable - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to delete multiple records in a database based on selections from check boxes in a form.  But if multiple check boxes are selected, the current sql only deletes first id for some reason, and not deleting the rest.

```
$del_ids = implode(',', array_keys($_POST['check_list'])); 
$query = "DELETE FROM enhancements WHERE id IN('$del_ids')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

For example my array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [check_list] => Array
        (
            [4] => on
            [6] => on
        )
)
```

And after running:

```
$del_ids = implode(',', array_keys($_POST['check_list']));
```

my `$del_ids` string looks like this:

```
4,6
```

But for some reason only record with id 4 deletes, and record with id 6 does not delete and they should both delete.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure del_ids contains multiple values?

Comment: it seems you are quoting the IN values , resulting in something like `IN ('4,6')`

Comment: Change `WHERE id IN('".$del_ids."')` to `WHERE id IN(".$del_ids.")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use this:

`$del_ids = implode("','", array_keys($_POST['check_list']));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM enhancements WHERE id IN('".$del_ids."')";
```

sends keys like a string, try replace with

```
$query = "DELETE FROM enhancements WHERE id IN(".$del_ids.")";
```

and it should work

Answer (score -1):

either run muliple delete statements, or append OR clauses in your statement.

The array you have with the ids to delete needs to be enumerated, you could go with something like this :

```
        foreach($_POST['check_list']as $key) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM enhancements WHERE id IN('".$key."')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
```

Comment: and the fact that you're using `as $key` instead of `$key => $value`, you'll get those `on` values instead of the actual key, this will yield `IN('on')`